# Saving time as UTC without DST (moment)

Tags: datetime, momentjs, dst

I have an issue trying figure out logic for storing time in database in UTC and handling DST changes.

I have TimeStart and TimeEnd in Database which indicates business hours. Problem occurs if I save hours while it's DST and while it's not. If I save **09:00 - 17:00** on October 15th, it would result **07:00 - 15:00** (UTC) but if I would add business hours now when it's not DST it would result **08:00 - 16:00** (UTC). I thought that when converting with moment to UTC would give consistent result taking DST in consideration but I was wrong.

What's best solution to handle that on frontend/backend. Should I substract added DST time? Because using moment to handle conversion to UTC doesn't help as it gives 1 hour difference anyway (now I question everything I did so far with UTC times as problems can probably occur due this issue).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The advice "always use UTC" is shortsighted. There are many cases to *not* use UTC, and the one you described is certainly among them.  The fact is, UTC is not good for future scheduling - especially with recurrence patterns.

Simply store the local start and end time of the business hours, without a date.  You might also want to store the time zone identifier (such as `"America/Los_Angeles"`) of that business's location.

When determining the business hours for a specific date, then apply the time from your database to the date in the business's time zone.  To know if the business is open or not, convert the *result* to UTC to test against the current UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the necessary reputation to simply leave a comment, I guess I'll write an actual answer. (Disclaimer: I haven't actually worked with moment.js)

I would recommend you always store time as UTC in your database. Conversion should happen when displaying/storing in frontend.

For more info on how to handle DST I found this great question with a lot of answers. You should be able to apply a lot of the stuff mentioned there to any stack:
[Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

Given the details in the question, it's hard to tell you where your error is, that you're still getting wrong values.

Comment: Thanks, I always have stored times as UTC in my database but I feel like there was always this issue with DST. My exact issue is if user comes and stores business hours in UTC when there's DST, that will result saving 07:00 (utc) in Database (as I'm in +2 zone). But if user adds business hours now then there's no DST it will result as 08:00 in database (as utc). There's that inconsistency... I'm using moment(date).utc() to convert from local to UTC.

Comment: Oh. I see. I guess storing the location of the business (timezone) is relevant here.